# Separate file & directories in PHP

Tags: php, ftp

PHP code used for listing the files and directories.

```
$buff = ftp_nlist($conn_id,$dir );
```

$buff is an array of both files & directories.

Is there a way to get 2 seperate arrays , 1 contains just files and other just directories.

Comment: No, ftp_nlist only returns one list of names, you can not say if those are directories or files. You might want to look into the FTP url wrapper: http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.ftp.php , it supports `is_dir()` for example. See also http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-rawlist.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could loop through the array and check wheter the item is a directory by using a function like

```
function ftp_is_dir($conn_id, $dir) {
  if (ftp_chdir($conn_id, $dir)) {
    ftp_chdir($conn_id, '..');
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

EDIT:

Another possibility would be

```
<?php
function is_ftp_dir($file, $conn_id){
if(ftp_size($conn_id, $file) == '-1'){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
}
?>
```

Please note that not every ftp server supports ftp_size().

Answer (score 3):

From [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nlist.php):

> `directory`
>
> The directory to be listed. *This parameter can also include arguments*, eg. ftp_nlist($conn_id, "-la /your/dir"); Note that this parameter isn't escaped so there may be some issues with filenames containing spaces and other characters.

So perform `ftp_nlist` twice: once providing arguments that give you only files, and then providing arguments that give you only directories. *This will rely on the system where the FTP server sites*.

Alternatively, you can employ [this more verbose solution](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nlist.php#78447) that uses `ftp_chdir`, or [this one](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nlist.php#78280) that uses `ftp_size`.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try [`ftp_rawlist()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-rawlist.php)? This function returns an array containing rows like:

```
06-21-11  01:49PM       <DIR>          01
06-21-11  02:20PM       <DIR>          02
06-21-11  03:33AM                  456 default.html
06-21-11  04:59PM                  123 robots.txt
```

Or:

```
drwxr-xr-x   12 ftp      ftp          4096 Mar 25  1999 ACS
drwxr-xr-x   14 ftp      ftp          4096 Mar 18  2001 ATHENA
drwxr-xr-x    2 ftp      ftp          4096 Jul 10  1998 XNeXT
drwxr-xr-x    3 ftp      ftp          4096 Jul 10  1998 elib
drwxrwxr-x  349 ftp      ftp         98304 Jul 02 06:30 gnu
drwxr-xr-x    3 ftp      ftp          4096 Jul 10  1998 lpf
-rw-r--r--    1 ftp      ftp       3448992 Oct 16  2003 ls-lR
drwxr-xr-x    2 ftp      ftp          4096 Jul 10  1998 palladium
drwxr-xr-x    2 ftp      ftp          4096 Jul 10  1998 palladium2
drwxr-xr-x    2 ftp      ftp          4096 Jul 10  1998 virus
```

From this point forward you can use [`ftp_systype()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-systype.php) function to determine how to interpret the above responses.

Or use heuristics e.g. on Windows the directories will contain the string `<DIR>` where as on Linux you should find each directory beginning with `d` followed by something like `rwxrwxrwx`.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to pattern match the files you need.  If you are able to rely on files having extensions and directories without a "." in, you can get all the filenames rather simply like so:

`$filenames = ftp_nlist( $conn_id, '*.*' );`