# PHP - Identifying directories vs files in FTP

Tags: php, foreach, ftp

I have the following PHP code that connects to an FTP server and loops through each item in the directory as a file. Problem is, some of these items are directories and I would like to be able to differentiate between the directories and files. If it's a directory then the icon file needs to change.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Thanks

```
$icon = "<img src=\"/icons/file.png\" border="\0\">";

$conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
$login = ftp_login($conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_password);
$files = ftp_nlist($conn, ".");
ftp_close($conn); 

foreach ($files as $file) {
    echo $icon." - ".$file."<br />";
}
```

Comment: otherwise this comment on php.net can help -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nlist.php#54307

Comment: It is a directory if you can `ftp_chdir()` into it. There is no other way to determine this server-side. See duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function just returns the `string array`.

You can use `ftp_rawlist` function. [Documnetation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-rawlist.php)

In this you can get TYPE as below:

```
 $children = ftp_rawlist($connetion, $directory);

 foreach ($children as $child) { 
    $chunks = preg_split("/\s+/", $child);
    $type=($chunks[0]{0} === 'd' ? 'directory' : 'file'); 
    $name=implode(' ', array_splice($chunks, 0, 8));
    //do whatever you want with $name & $type  || if($type=='file') echo $icon." - ".$name."<br />";
 }
```

---

**2nd Option**: And as mentioned in question comment that you can call function `ftp_chdir` to ftp_server. [link_for_this_method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557154/separate-file-directories-in-php) | But requesting FTP server each time for all list will take time.

Comment: Thanks. But to get the filename, I had to modify the  ($chunks, 0, 8) to read 0, 9 and then to echo the name I had to do $name[8]. Is this correct?

Comment: `ftp_rawlist()` returns the directory listing in a format determined by the server. You need to parse that differently per FTP server edition.

Comment: @John Not correct, that will give you correct result if filename don't have space in name. That's why you need to store all the elements in array after 8th index. then join those by `implode`. See edited answer. See next comment for reply to CodeCaster's if want.

Comment: @CodeCaster: you are right. My view is every developer have specific server until any change or update. So, it will be good to determine server first then use this solution, rather then querying server each time for all list to determine folder/directory and file. OTHERWISE developer may choose duplicate question's answer. :) || determining server, print 1 $child and check that at which index filename exists. inside for loop `echo $child; break;` OR for better details use `var_dump($chunks);break;`